# snakemake: copying a file to multiple folders

Tags: snakemake

I'm new to snakemake.  I have a rule to copy a file to multiple folders.   The folders are made in python.
I must be misunderstanding something about working with multiple targets. 
The following code, when run with "Snakemake practice_phased_reversed.vcf"
returns "No rule to produce practice_phased_reversed.vcf"

```
s=['k_1','k2_10']
fullfs = []
import os
cdir = os.getcwd()
for f in fs:
        path = os.path.join(cdir,f)
        fullfs.append(path)
        try:
                os.mkdir(path)
        except:
                pass
rule r1:
        input:
                "{basename}_phased_reversed.vcf"
        output:
                expand("{f}/{{basename}}_phased_reversed.vcf",f=fullfs)
        shell:
               "cp {input} {output}"
```

Comment: This means that a rule (r1) needs that file as input, but Snakemake can not find it.. And since it can not find it, it will look for a way to generate that file.

Comment: Thanks,  but I'm still missing something.  "snakemake --nocolor -n  practice" returns "No rule to produce practice'.   However practice_phased_reversed.vcf   is definitely in the same directory as Snakefile

Comment: You should use snakemake --nocolor -n yourdir/practice_phased_reversed.vcf. You specify which files you want, not which wildcards you want to use

Comment: doh! I should have seen that.

Comment: I got it to run when putting the file filename on the command line,  but not when using wildcards,  e.g. running this with snakemake --nocolor -n practice_phased_reversed.vcf 
 gives  "no values given for wildcard 'base' "run dirs=['k_1','k2_10']
rule all:
        input:
                expand("{f}/{base}_phased_reversed.vcf",f=dirs)
rule r1:
        input:
                "{base}_phased_reversed.vcf"
        output:
                "{f}/{input}"
        shell:
               "cp {input} {output}"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Maarten-vd-Sande.   Now this works using "snakemake"  i.e. without passing a target file name.

```
dirs=['k_1','k2_10']
rule all:
        input:
                expand("{f}/practice_phased_reversed.vcf",f=dirs)
rule r1:
        input:
                "practice_phased_reversed.vcf"
        output:
                "{f}/practice_phased_reversed.vcf"
        shell:
               "cp {input} {output}"
```

But I am still missing something.  I need to be able to call this with a target,  i.e. "snakemake practice_phased_reversed.vcf"   Thanks for any help.